# с C++ на Python

Tags: python, c++

решил опробовать свои в одной задачке, но не получилось :( А получилось только на С++, можете ли вы помочь с переписыванием кода на С++ в Python код вот С++ код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str1 = nullptr;
string str2 = nullptr;
bool ans = false;
cout << "input first string" << endl;
cin >> str1;
cout << "input second string" << endl;
cin >> str2;
if (str1.size() == str2.size()){
for (int i = 0; i<str1.size(); i++){
        if (str1[i] == str2[i]) {
            ans = true;
        } else {
            ans = false;
            break;
        }
    }
} 
if (ans) cout << "lines are equal" << endl;
else cout << "lines are not equal" << endl;
     
return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcmp - не не слышали...

Comment: @eri, зачем `strcmp`? Достаточно `==`.

Comment: В си плюсплюс можно сравнивать строки через ==?

Comment: @eri Можно, если это не сырые массивы байт.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("lines are equal" 
    if input("input first string") == input("input second string") 
    else "lines are not equal"
)
```

Тут всё настолько просто что даже не знаю как прокомментировать.

По совету @avp более развернуто. Для начала буквальный перевод:

```
str1 = input("input first string")
str2 = input("input second string")
ans = False
if len(str1) == len(str2):
    for i in range(len(str1)):
         if str1[i] == str2[i]:
             ans = True
         else:
             ans = False
             break
if ans:
    print("lines are equal")
else:
    print("lines are not equal")
```

Comment: Издеваетесь над студентом?

Comment: @avp, тут только инлайн иф не изучают на первом уроке по питону... Но после третьего урока это можно сделать на обычном if... Прогульщик тут, а не студент)

Comment: И что теперь с ним делать? Учить или сразу в расход? Лучше добавьте  доступный ему пример кода (императивный, с парой переменных, из 5 строк)

Comment: @avp цитируя правила закрытия вопросов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Остается надяться, что мы подтолкнули ТС в нужном направлении и промежуточные шаги к более "питонистому" коду он уже сам пройдет

Comment: неа, автор просто удалит этот вопрос когда пойдет сдавать домашку.

Comment: @eri не сможет - на вопрос есть ответ. Да и зачем ему трудиться?